# Sprite kit doesn't find nodeAtPoint after moving parent SKNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision-detection, sprite-kit

**Hi.**

I'm having this weird problem in Sprite Kit. I'm using `nodeAtPoint` and `categoryBitMask` to detect whether the player is touching the ground when calling a jump method.

Everything's working as it should. But then — in order to reveal some optional buttons in a drawer — when I move the parent node with `SKAction moveTo:CGPoint` (I have both the ground and player as children of an `SKNode`), the player don't jump. I NSLog the `pointBelowPlayer`, and it is the same as before, but the `blockNode.physicsBody` is null! Might this be a bug in Sprite Kit, or am I missing something basic about inheritance and position?

**The method for jumping:**

```
-(void)playerJump {

    // Player jump if on ground
    CGPoint pointBelowPlayer = CGPointMake(_player.position.x, _player.position.y-_player.size.height);
    SKNode *blockNode = [self nodeAtPoint:pointBelowPlayer];

    if (blockNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == groundCategory){
        [_player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 120.0f)];
    }
}
```

**The method for moving the parent node:**

```
-(void)toggleDrawer {
    if (bDrawerVisible) {
        [_actionLayer runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(0, 0) duration:1]];
        bDrawerVisible = false;
    } else {
        [_actionLayer runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(0, 200) duration:1]];
        bDrawerVisible = true;
    }
}
```

**Creation of the SpriteNodes:**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        _actionLayer = [SKNode new];

        _player = [self createPlayer];
        [_actionLayer addChild:_player];

        _ground = [self createGround];
        [_actionLayer addChild:_ground];
}

-(SKSpriteNode *)createPlayer {

    SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"redSquare.png"];
    player.name = @"player";
    player.scale = 0.5;
    player.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/3, player.size.height*2);
    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.size];
    player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory;
    player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = noteCategory;

    return player;
}

-(SKSpriteNode *)createGround {

    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ground.png"];
    ground.name = @"ground";
    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;
    ground.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;
    ground.xScale = screenWidth/ground.size.width;;
    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 0);

    return ground;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i solve the problem...
if you have more then one Node, on the position you tap, you will get null if the deepest node have no name, or the name of the deepest Node.

So use this to go through all nodes are found:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
NSArray *buttonNodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];
for (SKNode *node in buttonNodes)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", node.name);
}
```

Additional you can use `NSLog(@"%f", node.zPosition);` to get the zPosition to see witch one is on top.

Comment: just to clarify, nodeAtPoint returns the deepest node at the point, and nodesAtPoint returns an array of all nodes at that point.

Comment: this solved a problem I had moving from iOS7 to iOS8 with my SK App. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Node at point might be another node (maybe your background?).
Use node.name to name the nodes and you may check if node if the same by comparing names with equalToString: method.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! It's early in the development, I don't have any background at the moment — node.name returns (null) after the parent movement (and "ground" before), so there are no other nodeAtPoint.

Comment: @Brean It will return null, since the name is not set. Set different names for your nodes and log names again and see what happens.

Comment: The ground node is already named, as you can see from my code above. If I NSLog the node at pointBelowPlayer, it returns:`<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}` as if the ground isn't there.